# Extracting help message from script itself

Tags: shell-script, sed, documentation

I want that my help message be extracted from the script itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# foo - do things
# Author: John Doe <jhon@doe>
# ----------------------------------------------
# SYNOPSIS
#   foo [OPTIONS] FILE
# 
# DESCRIPTION
#   At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
#   dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesenti
#   voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos.
# ----------------------------------------------

sed -n '/# -\+$/,/# -\+$/ p' $0
```

It works! It prints only what is between the two `# -\+$` delimiters, inclusive. The problem is that I don't want print the delimiters.

And do you have suggestions for a man page generator with human friendly syntax?

**Update:** Maybe stated my problem poorly. I want to print only what is between the two lines starting with `# -----` and ending with `----`.

I know this solution:

```
sed -n '/# -\+$/,/# -\+$/ p' $0 | head -n -1 | tail -n +2
```

But I want a clean and elegant solution that doesn't look hackish.

Comment: Removing the `cat/which` would be cleaner, `$0` already holds the full path to the binary, so `sed ... $0` would do.

Comment: @Thor a lot better...

Comment: [shocco.sh](http://rtomayko.github.com/shocco/) does it similarly, but uses an additional prefix character for documentation comments.

Comment: @manatwork [schocco](http://rtomayko.github.com/shocco/) is awesome. [ronn](http://rtomayko.github.com/ronn/ronn.1.html) (from same author) is nice too: converts markdown to roff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# foo - do things
# Author: John Doe <jhon@doe>
# ----------------------------------------------
# SYNOPSIS
#   foo [OPTIONS] FILE
# 
# DESCRIPTION
#   At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
#   dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesenti
#   voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos.
# ----------------------------------------------


cat `which $0` | sed -n '0,/# -\+$/d;/# -\+$/,$d;p'
```

Comment: Haha, you got it :-)

Comment: Then it's time to go for a sleep )

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish this with `awk`:

```
awk '/^# --/{ flag=!flag; next}; flag' file
```

Given that the text you are using to delimit the desired text is the same at the beginning and end, ie., `# --`, the normal [range pattern](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_9.html#SEC92) will fail so you need to use a flag. The [next statement](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_77.html) forces awk to move to the next record, before printing the range.

Comment: It prints the desired output, plus two blank lines and then the `cat ...` line.

Comment: I'd love to see an `awk` solution.

Comment: Sorry: I misread the question...

Comment: Oh, thanks. Do you mind explain a bit?

Comment: Updated: hope that helps.

Comment: Despite its great usefulness, `awk` has an `awk`ward syntax.

Comment: Boom tish! :-) .

Answer (score 2):

You could do it pretty simply with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='\n# -+' 'NR==2' $0
```

`RS` sets to record separator appropriately and `NR==2` prints the second record.

You can remove the comment sign and extra space with `gsub`, e.g.:

```
awk -v RS='\n# -+' 'NR==2 { gsub("\n# ", "\n"); print }' $0
```

**Update**

To avoid an empty first line add `\n` to `RS`, but now the first line is not substituted by `gsub`, so `gensub` is called for:

```
awk -v RS='\n# -+\n' 'NR==2 { print gensub("(^|\n)# ", "\\1", "g") }' $0
```

Comment: Very understandable answer. The first line is empty, I tried to remove with `gsub(/\n?\n# /, "\n")` without success.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll add and update that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're needing is called a "here document." Fortunately, it's already implemented in bash. Check out the following URL [http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.htm](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)l

You simply use the following:

```
cat <<end-of-message
----------------------------
message lines...
----------------------------
end-of-message
```

You can add a conditional at the top of your script to print that only if a parameter is input or something... like a -h option or if there are no arguments present.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how heredocs could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than sticking your message into the comments at the beginning of the file, you can also emulate the `__DATA__` section of Perl and some other programming languages by exiting before the script reaches it:

```
#!/bin/sh

data=$(sed '0,/^__DATA__$/d' "$0")
printf '%s\n' "$data"

exit

__DATA__
FOO BAR BAZ
LLAMA DUCK COW
```

Same general idea as the other sed-based solutions, though.

Comment: Man, this is cool. I liked the idea of meta info (beyond comments) stored on source code. I prefer documentation on top, but sure I'll find some use for this.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '/^# -\+$/,//!d;//d' $0
```

Explanation:

- `/^# -\+$/,//!d` delete everything not between delimiters
- `//d` delete the delimiters and let the remainder pass through

N.B. `//` reuses the latest regexp.

Comment: If this works will be the best solution IMO.